# How do I copy an item from a ko.mapping.fromJS Array to another property of the viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here's something that used to work in existing code that ran on Knockout 2, that I'm refactoring to Knockout 3.

The properties of the viewmodel are initialized from a feed (simplified code):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/GetData",
    data: {
        clientId: clientId
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        viewModel.periods(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
        viewModel.selectedPeriod = ko.observable(viewModel.periods()[0]);
    },
    async: false
});
```

The `viewModel.selectedPeriod =` line works when I debug the value, but the binding does not work.

So this fails ...

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedPeriod.Years">
    <li data-bind="text: Year"></li>
</ul>
```

... while this works:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: periods">
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Years">
            <li data-bind="text: Year"></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've reproduced my problem in a simplified Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/frankvaneykelen/w3opn442/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few changes to your code ...

```
viewModel.selectedPeriod(viewModel.periods()[0]); // observable method call instead of assigning
```

....

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: selectedPeriod().Years">  // resolve the observable first ...
```

a working code can be found here

https://jsfiddle.net/0cLtvqz0/4/

Comment: I like the "with" by @dperry approach it makes sure the binding doesn't throw exception if the "selectedPeriod" is null at any point. But the selectedPeriod method still needs to be assigned as an observable if the binding is to truly reflect value changes

Comment: Thank you! The observable method call did the trick! I already had the `with: selectedPeriod` in my project's code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `with` binding to properly narrow your context:

https://jsfiddle.net/lobotomize/w3opn442/13/

note the `with` binding on the outer div

```
    <div class="col-xs-6" data-bind="with: selectedPeriod">
         <h5>selectedPeriod.Years</h5>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Years">
            <li data-bind="text: Year"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```